# How to calculate CPU percentage from Digital Ocean API

Tags: performance, cpu, monitoring, digital-ocean

I have call Digital Ocean API for monitoring, and here is the response from Digital Ocean.

[Replit link](https://replit.com/join/ctasclrnjf-nguyenquangphuc)

I don't understand these modes, such as 'idle' or 'iowait' and how to calculate %CPU from these index, please help me !!! thank you all !!!

Answer (score 0):

total = idle + iowait + irq + nice + softirq + steal + system + user

percent = ( 1 - ( idle / total ) ) * 100;